# recurrence relation : find bit strings of length seven contain two consecutive 0 in C

Tags: c, recurrence

i have the recurrence relation of

[image]

and the initials condition is

> a0 = a1 = 0

with these two, i have to find the bit strings of length 7 contain two consecutive 0 which i already solve.

example:

```
a2 = a2-1 + a2-2 + 22-2
= a1 + a0 + 20
= 0 + 0 + 1
= 1
```

and so on until a7.

**the problem is how to convert these into c?**

im not really good at c but i try it like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{   
    int a[7];
    int total = 0;
    printf("the initial condition is a0 = a1 = 0\n\n");

//  a[0] = 0;
//  a[1] = 0;

    for (int i=2; i<=7; i++)
    {
        if(a[0] && a[1])
        a[i] = 0;
        else
        total = (a[i-1]) + (a[i-2]) + (2 * pow((i-2),i));
        printf("a%d = a(%d-1) + a(%d-2) + 2(%d-2)\n",i,i,i,i);
        printf("a%d = %d\n\n",i,total); 
    }   
}
```

the output are not the same as i calculate pls help :(

Comment: Why is the initialization of `a[0]` and `a[1]` commented out?  And in the `if` statement, how come you test `a[0] && a[1]` every time?  Don't you want to test something different depending on `i`?

Comment: (2 * pow((i-2),i)) != 2^(n-2);

(2 * pow((i-2),i)) = 2*((i-2)^i);

Comment: You access index out of bounds ,enough  for undefined behaviour .

Comment: I am certain that you observed that C does not initialize variable declarations to 0 automatically, and you leveraged this feature in your example... but it is helpful to your audience when you post in this forum to initialize so that we can create reproducible answers for you.

Comment: As **ameyCU** said... there is an out-of-bounds... which means specifically that you should change the condition in the for loop from i<=7 to i<7 -- using the < sign in this way when traversing an array with a for statement is also "idiomatic C."

Comment: Also, when you compute `total`, don't you want to assign it to `a[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
int func (int n) 
{
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return 0;
    if (n==2)
        return 1;
    return func(n-1) + func(n-2) + pow(2,(n-2));
}

#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{   
    return func(7);
}
```

Comment: thank you! although this will show only the last answer that is a7. what if i want to show the answer from a1 through a7?

Comment: You will have to call it for n=2...7 and save each result at a time in an array.

Answer (score 0):

In the pow() function, pow(x,y) = x^y (which operates on doubles and returns double).  The C code in your example is thus doing 2.0*(((double)i-2.0)^(double)i)... A simpler approach to 2^(i-2) (in integer math) is to use the bitwise shift operation:

```
total = a[i-1] + a[i-2] + (1 << i-2);
```

*(Note: For **ANSI C operator precedence** consult an internet search engine of your choice.)*

If your intention is to make the function capable of supporting floating point, then the pow() function would be appropriate...  but the types of the variables would need to change accordingly.

For integer math, you may wish to consider using a long or long long type so that you have less risk of running out of headroom in the type.

Answer (score 0):

First of uncomment the lines which initialized the 2 first elements. Then at the for loop the only 2 lines need are:

a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2]+pow(2, i-2);
And then print a i